# trouble SIGABRT in boost thread_group

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, boost

I got a trouble in boost::thread_group

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::thread_group threadpool;

boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);


for (int i = 0; i  < num_threads; i++) {
    threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
}

boost::thread *t_proxy = 0;

if (!without_proxy)
{
    t_proxy = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ThreadPool::w_proxy, this, proxy_link));
}


int task_size = tasks.size();
for (int i = 0; i < task_size; i++) {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
    working_threads++;

    ioService.post(boost::bind(&ThreadPool::thread_worker, this));
    tasks.pop_front();


ioService.stop();


if (t_proxy)
{
    t_proxy->join();
}

threadpool.join_all();
```

`&ThreadPool::w_proxy` - thread, which checks proxy in a background and saves it into common list
`&ThreadPool::thread_worker` - worker function, which uses proxy from the common list and does some functions
tasks  vector with task list
`_mutex` - boost::mutex used for sync proxy list and `thread_worker` result
trouble point:
in process I got a  SIGABRT in string
t_proxy->join();
or in
threadpool.join_all();

I`ve tried to add  w_proxy in general thread_group, and I got same trouble
threadpool.join_all();

I have a traceback in *condition_variable.hpp*
The failed function is `condition_variable::wait`  in line

```
res = pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&internal_mutex);
```

could you help me with it?